# turn 2d array into 1d PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array (sample below) containing 3 arrays with very similar content. I was wondering if there was an easy way to put everything into one array, rather than 3 separate ones. Everything I try seems to just overwrite the data and I'm left with the info from the 3rd array only.

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'america' => int 19
      'music' => int 6
      'states' => int 5
      'bank' => int 5
  1 => 
    array
      'america' => int 19
      'home' => int 3
      'society' => int 2
      'writers' => int 2
   2 => 
    array
      'america' => int 19
      'lutheran' => int 4
      'church' => int 4
      'national' => int 4
      'cruises' => int 3
```

Ideally the end result will look like this:

```
array
          'america' => int 19
          'music' => int 6
          'states' => int 5
          'bank' => int 5
          'america' => int 19
          'home' => int 3
          'society' => int 2
          'writers' => int 2
          'america' => int 19
          'lutheran' => int 4
          'church' => int 4
          'national' => int 4
          'cruises' => int 3
```

Any solutions? thanks

Comment: A 2D array is probably the simplest option. Why do you want it to be 1D?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to have an associative array with the same key values (i.e. 3 keys of "America", etc.).  When you try to set those keys in the array, you will simply overwrite the previous value.

Comment: Ok i understand, does that mean the integer value would be overwritten too? The int is the important part really.

Comment: Well if you are looping through the 2D array and they trying to do something like: "$one_dim_array[$two_dim_array_key] = $two_dim_array_value;", then you will simply overwrite the value in the 1D array for each duplicate 2D array key value.

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if there was an easy way to put everything into one
>   array

Short answer is no.

You could make a class with a variable for the original int and a value for the number of times it occurs and then have the array point to objects of the class. Same idea could be implemented using a linked list, though both ways are more complex than what you already have.

For example the key 'america' would point to an object with one variable set to 19 and the other variable set to 3.

**Question:** do you need to know which of the original arrays a value comes from? If yes then what I mentioned above would loose that property.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: I tried array_merge like this:

$test = array_merge($cluster[0], $cluster[1]);

didn't work, am I using it incorrectly?

Comment: what is your result in $test or are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Thanks for your input everyone, I ended up just going about it a different way. I was a litte bit silly with my code previous to the array being set up like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
function array_2d_to_1d($array)
                                    {
                                        $my_val=array();
                                        $my_key=array();
                                        foreach ($array as $value) {
                                             array_push($my_val, $value['cat_title']);
                                             array_push($my_key, $value['cat_id']);
                                         }

                                        $result = array_combine($my_key, $my_val);
                                        return $result;

                                    }
```

Comment: you should add some explanation